# Is it possible to pack 5 bits in perl?

Tags: perl, pack

For example, let's say I want to pack the following bits: 11111 which is 31 in decimal.  How can I pack these 5 bits? I don't want to pack 8 bits or 1 byte.  I need to pack only 5 bits; 11111

b5 "11111" doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Pack into _what_? The smallest unit you can read or write is 8 bits.  The question doesn't make sense as written.

Comment: Yes, but you read 5 bits from a byte by setting the unused bits to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

works for me :

```
  print  oct "0b11111";
  31
  print ord(pack("b*","11111"));
  31
```